# PHP: How to merge two "valueless" arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, merge

I found and adapted an example which scans an array for an entry like so:

```
$ignoredFileTypes = array('svn','fla','bak','db');
if( array_search('.fla',$ignoredFileTypes) > -1 ){
    return true;
}
```

It worked well for my initial needs.

Now, I am trying to join two arrays like so:

```
$ignoredFileTypes = array('svn','fla','bak','db');
$customIgnoredFileTypes = array('txt', 'xsd');
$ignoredFileTypes = array_merge( $ignoredFileTypes , $customIgnoredFileTypes );
```

Unfortunately, that generates a warning like so:

```
Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array in C:\wamp\www\packager.php on line 41
```

So a couple of questions:

1. Is using the above array creation syntax incorrect?
2. How can I properly create these two arrays so that they can be merged?

Thanks!
d

Comment: So then what does `$ignoredFileTypes` *actually* contain?

Comment: I tried running your code and it works just fine for me.

Comment: That question could be answered by the person who wrote the example I adapted. It contains nothing? I suspect that array_search works because it is searching keys, but the merge doesn't work because the keys have no values? My keys... don't need values, the key values are as detailed as my array *needs* to be. Is it that they *must* have values?

Comment: I agree with icktoofay. Please paste in your actual, non-working code.

Comment: Thank you for the jolt, slightly embaressing, I hadn't defined a global - $ignoredFileTypes - which is defined outside of the function which does the merge. Sorry guys :/

Comment: @Danjah Sounds like some terrible design going on there.

Comment: @Danjah: Either add that as an answer or select the answer below as "the answer". This will mark your question as solved. Thanks!

Comment: @Phil - actually it's a 60 line PHP file that copies required files to a different place. Its both efficient and useful, its simplicity and directness allows me to achieve the task at hand - therefore it is well designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arrays aren't "valueless", they are just numeric arrays.  The values are the strings (`'svn'`, `'fla'`, etc.).

The [PHP docs for `array_merge`](http://us.php.net/array_merge) says:

> Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.

The syntax you posted...

```
<?php

$ignoredFileTypes = array('svn','fla','bak','db');
$customIgnoredFileTypes = array('txt', 'xsd');
$ignoredFileTypes = array_merge( $ignoredFileTypes , $customIgnoredFileTypes );
print_r($ignoredFileTypes);
```

Works perfectly for me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => svn
    [1] => fla
    [2] => bak
    [3] => db
    [4] => txt
    [5] => xsd
)
```